# vb.net textbox.text not updating

Tags: vb.net

In VS2015 using VB, I have a winform that uses another winform (instantiated from a class) as a message display to show current status of a series of rows in a table.  When I first update the message display and show it, the textbox displays the message, however subsequent calls to update the textbox fail to display (I allow setting of textbox.text when first initiating the form, but am not using that option here).  I have traced the action in the debugger and the txtStatus.text property is updated correctly in the set method of MessageText - it just doesn't display.  Curiously, if I set .tabstop to false for the textbox, the textbox doesn't display any data at all.  A second (probably related) problem is that I also have a button on the message form, that button fails to display at all (the display shows a white box where the button should be).  There is nothing unusual about the button, I have only set up the .text property.  It is as if I have created multiple instances of MssgClass and am updating the wrong one, but as far as I can tell, I have instantiated only one instance.

I have reviewed all the documents and questions I can find regarding this problem, but haven't been able to find a solution.

here is code for the calling form:

Public Class myform

```
.
.
Dim oMessage As New MssgClass("")
For nIndex As Integer = 0 To oDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    .
    .
    oMessage.MessageText = "My Message"
    oMessage.Show()
    .
    ' index this table - MyIndex is a com object MyIndex.dll
    iIndexed = MyIndex.IndexFile("the table name")
    '

Next
oMessage.close()
```

End Class

here is code for MssgClass: (holds a textbox named txtStatus)

Public Class MssgClass

```
Public Property MessageText() As String
    Get
        Return Me.txtStatus.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal pcMssg As String)
        Me.txtStatus.Text = pcMssg
        Me.txtStatus.Show()
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New(ByVal pcMssg As String)
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.txtStatus.Text = pcMssg
End Sub
```

End Class

the MssgClass form is set with borderstyle of FixedDialog,
controlbox is false (I don't want any controls that the user can operate other than the button I provide), topmost is true.  Here is the InitializeComponent method:

Private Sub InitializeComponent()

```
Me.txtStatus = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
Me.SuspendLayout()
'
'txtStatus
'
Me.txtStatus.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control
Me.txtStatus.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
Me.txtStatus.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12.0!, 
   System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 
   CType(0, Byte))
Me.txtStatus.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(25, 22)
Me.txtStatus.Multiline = True
Me.txtStatus.Name = "txtStatus"
Me.txtStatus.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(414, 20)
Me.txtStatus.TabIndex = 0
Me.txtStatus.Text = "Textbox"
Me.txtStatus.TextAlign = System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment.Center
'
'Button1
'
Me.Button1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12.0!, 
    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, 
    CType(0, Byte))
Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(174, 59)
Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(118, 35)
Me.Button1.TabIndex = 1
Me.Button1.Text = "Cancel"
Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
'
'MssgClass
'
Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(474, 115)
Me.ControlBox = False
Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
Me.Controls.Add(Me.txtStatus)
Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog
Me.MaximizeBox = False
Me.MinimizeBox = False
Me.Name = "MssgClass"
Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
Me.TopMost = True
Me.ResumeLayout(False)
Me.PerformLayout()
```

End Sub

I am assuming I have done something (or failed to do something) in MssgClass, I just have no idea what.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: interesting idea, but where would that be happening?  My .close call happens outside the for loop where the updating occurs.  Also, the message form does stay displayed throughout - can a closed form still display?

Comment: Guessing you are closing the form and not showing it again.  You probably want ShowDialog instead.

Comment: I thought showdialog stopped the progress of the calling form method until a return was initiated from the called form.  In this case, I need the calling form method to continue processing while the message form is displayed.  Otherwise the user would be forced to click an OK button to allow the process to proceed for every record.  No?

Comment: Sure, but what's the point of putting your message box in that loop?  The user will only see the message for the last item in the loop.

Comment: The process that takes place is indexing, which for large tables with many indexes can take time.  The purpose is to keep the user informed of progress table by table (a progress bar is insufficient in this case - in my opinion).  The user should see each table name displayed (unless it is a small table with few indexes, that would be processed to quickly for the display)

Comment: Looping through a table's rows collection is going to be instantaneous to the user.  If you have a long running operation, then you need to use a BackgroundWorker or Async/Await and report the changes to the main thread.

Comment: I'll have to look into that option.  In the mean time, a status message form is a very handy thing to have for many functions, and I'd like to know why this implementation fails.  At the least I'll learn something, and at the best I'll get my status form working AND learn something!.

Comment: If a process is running on the main thread, it will prevent GUI updates from happening.  That's why you need to do your non-GUI work in a separate thread and only update GUI controls on the main thread.

Comment: As far as I know, I am running a single thread.  There is no other process occurring when MssgClass is called.  The indexing itself is done in a com object which does not return until it has completed its task. Stepping through the code, as the code returns from the message form having (apparently) successfully updated the textbox, the .show method does not seem to cause the messagebox to update on screen, and the com object is not yet called at that point.  As you pointed out, the GUI update is not happening.  But with no other processing happening at that point, I'm not understanding why.

Comment: Your posted code doesn't show anything regarding a COM object.  All I see is you looping through what looks like a DataTable.  Instead of `Me.txtStatus.Show()`, try `Me.txtStatus.Update()`

Comment: I added the call to the original posting.  I didn't think it was relevant, but who am I to decide that!  I apologize for not including it before.  In the mean time,  Me.txtStatus.update() solved the problem!!!  THANK YOU Lars!!!  And I have learned through this too.  That makes this a good day!